# How to fix this CORS issue in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to connect to a remote server with socket.io, but I am having some problems. I am getting this error: The value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header in the response is ' ' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

OK, so here is the code:

Server

```js
var server = require('http').createServer();

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "my URL",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: false
  }
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Client has connected!");
});

console.log ('Server started.');
server.listen(3000);
```

Here is the client code:

```js
var socket = io.connect("https://persistent-gentle-banon.glitch.me", {
  withCredentials: false
});
```

How can I solve this and get it to connect?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, i was using express and i was able to solve it by

```
var cors = require("cors");
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["PUT", "GET", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    credentials: false
  }
  // transports: ['websocket']
});

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Do I keep the code the same for the client? Also what is the line you commented out for?

Comment: yea it can be the same

Comment: Hmm..... it does not seem to be working. Perhaps you missed some code?

Answer (score 1):

According to this link https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-instance/#serverengine , you should use io.engine **initial_headers** and **headers** events to set cors headers simply, this should work with socket.io v4+.

```
import { createServer } from "http";
import {Server} from  'socket.io';

const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

io.engine.on("initial_headers", (headers, req) => {
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "http://localhost:4200";
});

io.engine.on("headers", (headers, req) => {
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "http://localhost:4200"; // url to all
});

server.listen(3000);
```